# When to use "der" or "den"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, declension, standard-german

> Die Frau isst der Apfel.
>   Die Frau isst den Apfel.

Are these both the same?

Comment: Why did this receive a negative vote?  As a very early stages student, I had this exact question (which was easy to find thanks to it's Google search rank).

Answer (score 15):

Nouns and articles are conjugated according to the grammatical case we use. In your example the appropriate cases are:

> **Die Frau** (*Nominative*) isst **den Apfel** (*Accusative*).

Still, grammatically it is possible to use different cases in order to express a different action:

> **Die Frau** (*Accusative*) isst **der Apfel** (*Nominative*) = *the woman is being eaten by the apple*

With a female gender the singular article for nominative case and accusative case are the same.

See how the meaning changes with the following example:

> Der Mann *(N)* küsst die Frau *(A)* *vs.* Den Mann *(A)* küsst die Frau *(N)*

Comment: It’s also noteworthy that the verb (_essen_ in this case) determines which case its object has to be in (and some can rule more than one object). The case of the subject of a sentence is always _Nominativ_.

Comment: This is a good example why you can exchange the position of subject and object in German language, Nominative and Accusative make always clear which one we have. The English language doesn't have this case feature, and so you must keep the SPO order to make it clear what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same, but related. The answer is that the articles "der, die, das" are declined. You might have a look at the explanantion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_language#Noun_inflection) (I don't know of any easier right now).
In your example the line "Die Frau isst *den* Apfel" is the correct one. The article of "der Apfel" would change again if we would say "Die Frau isst den Kern *des* Apfels" (the core *of* the apple i.e. the genitive is used).

Even if the women eats a carrot (die Karotte), then the accusative is in use (although you can't see it because it looks the same as the "normal" (nominative) article: "Die Frau isst die Karotte".

Confusion around the articles are very common for non-native speakers, but thats not too bad since on most cases the meaning can be derived from context and people will still understand you.

Comment: `then the genitive is in use` ... nope, it's accusative

Comment: @devnull69: you are correct, I fixed my answer.

Comment: "ist den Kern des Apfels"? Meinst Du "ist der Kern" oder "isst den Kern"?